# How to cite a book chapter written by an author who is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I don't know how to cite a chapter written by an author who is not the editor or author of the book.

How can I get the following citation?

> Grandstrand, O. (2004), 'Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights', in J. Fagerberg, D.C. Mowery and R.R. Nelson (Eds.), Oxford Handbook of Innovation. Oxford University Press: Oxford.

Answer (score 171):

I believe that the entry type you want to use is called `@incollection`.

Back-filling information for the author's and editors' first names as well as the `chapter` and `pages` fields, the full entry could be as follows:

```
@incollection{grandstrand:2004,
  author      = "Ove Grandstrand",
  title       = "Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights",
  editor      = "Jan Fagerberg and David C. Mowery and Richard R. Nelson",
  booktitle   = "The Oxford Handbook of Innovation",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2004,
  pages       = "266-290",
  chapter     = 10,
}
```

Using the `plain` bibliography style would generate the following typeset entry:

[image]

**Addendum**: If you use the `chicago` bibliography style, you'll get:

[image]

Here's the code used to generate the two preceding screenshots:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @incollection{grandstrand:2004,
      author      = "Ove Grandstrand",
      title       = "Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights",
      editor      = "Jan Fagerberg and David C. Mowery and Richard R. Nelson",
      booktitle   = "The Oxford Handbook of Innovation",
      publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
      address     = "Oxford",
      year        = 2004,
      pages       = "266-290",
      chapter     = 10,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % or: "chicago"
\usepackage{natbib} % a citation management package

\begin{document}   
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect... But if you use another style, like Chicago Style, you can not see the author of the book.

Comment: @mmc -- I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by your claim. I've provided an addendum to my answer, to show the result if one uses the "chicago" instead of the "plain" bibliography style; both the author of the book chapter and the editors of the book itself are shown without a problem.

Comment: If you use Chicago style, I would recommend using `biblatex-chicago`, and following the most current edition of the manual (16th). The format shown is not current Chicago style.

Comment: Shouldn't page numbers be connected by an n-dash like `--`?

Comment: @FangJing - Not sure I undestand your question. Most bibliography style files I'm familiar with contain a function which *automatically* "dashifies" the `-` character if it occurs in the pages` field, i.e., changes it to an en-dash. Do check both screenshots I posted: sure enough, they feature an en-dash, not a simple dash, between the page numbers. In short `pages = "266-290",` and `pages = "266--290",` produce the same output with most bib styles I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Mico I see. That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Mico I deleted my comment to avoid confusion for future readers, since it was based on several wrong assumptions. I would be happy if you could do so too, as our conversation does not contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 43):

Perhaps not exactly how you want it to appear (that requires probably selecting the right bibtex style) but here is something close with the standard:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inbook{ X,
author = {O. Grandstrand},
chapter = {Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights},
crossref = {Y}
}

@book{ Y,
editor = {J. Fagerberg and D.C. Mowery and R.R. Nelson}, 
title      = {Oxford Handbook of Innovation},
booktitle = {Oxford Handbook of Innovation},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
address = {Oxford},
year = 2004
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

There are two reference here (both the chapter and the book) because I use `\notcite` on all antries. If just the chapter is cited then the result would be

[image]

The problem is that most if not all styles (that I know of) do not use both author and editor in a single entry even though it would make a lot of sense here. They only do that for `@inproceedings` and `@incollection` (I see that you found the latter by now yourself).

By default, BibTeX adds a separate citation to the whole book cross referenced when there are 2 or more different citations that crossref a complete work (even if the complete work is not explicitly cited anywhere. On modern BibTeX implementations this can be customized when running BibTeX by using the switch `--min-crossref=<number>`.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for as I want just to cite the chapter, and not the book.... I use Chicago or Harvard style, I forgot to mention...

Comment: This is due to me citing all entries (see updated answer). However the form "In XYZ" is only used by BibTeX (min most styles) for `@incollection` or `@inproceedings`.

Comment: When using biblatex, you may create a biblatex.cfg in your document root containing a line: `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{mincrossrefs=99}` to customize the min-crossref setting.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is *exactly* what I was looking for when I searched and found this question. Species description by Say in 1823 - in his field notes included as a chapter in a book he isn't credited as author of. Perfect match for this solution.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `crossref`!

Comment: Note that `crossref` behaves differently in bibtex and biblatex

Answer (score 14):

use

```
@inbook{test,
  author={Grandstrand, O.},
  year= 2004, 
  chapter={Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights}, 
  editor = {J. Fagerberg and D. C. Mowery and R. R. Nelson}, 
  title= {Oxford Handbook of Innovation}, 
  publisher= {Oxford University Press},
  address= {Oxford}, 
}
```

with `biblatex` and style `authoryear` I'll get:

[image]

Comment: that somehow comes out wrong, the chapter title is in the "in ..." part where it doesn't belong. Problem with biblatex?

Comment: here, the title of the chapter is missing...

Comment: @mmc no not missing, but in a strange place at the end of the entry. I think the resulting entry is wrong for this reason

Comment: @FrankMittelbach This is not a problem with `biblatex` - rather with the style `authoryear`. The style `chicago-authordate` looks about right, especially if one changes `title` into `booktitle`

Answer (score 2):

I tried using CROSSREF, but I found that the `\nocite{*}` generated too many entries.  I *don't* want all entries in my BIB file to show up in the References section of my paper.  The problem is that, without `\nocite{*}`, the book which contains the chapter/section that I'm citing does not show up.  I managed to solve this by citing the book from within the `\phantom` command.  So in the context of Frank Mittelbach's example, I would have the commend `\phantom{\cite{Y}}` somewhere in my document.  I placed it before the `\cite{X}` (the chapter/section within book Y in Frank Mittelbach's example).

Afternote: Darn.  It didn't really have the desired effect.  I have unwanted white space where the citation would have been made.  This is exactly how `\phantom` should work, so I don't know what I was thinking.  Can anyone suggest another way to hide the dummy citation to Y?  The only reason why it's there is so that the CROSSREF in X is properly handled.  Maybe a way to impose a zero-size font onto the dummy citation?  Using `\fontsize` and `\selectfont` to specify 0pt causes an error, so I tried making the dummy citation white: `\textcolor{white}{ \fontsize{1pt}{1pt}\selectfont \cite{Y} }`.  This only makes the square brackets around the bibliography entry number white.

I guess `@incollection` is the way to go.