# Citing a portion of a larger work

Tags: bibtex

I'm citing a technical report that is made up of a number of large chapters, each with their own authors. Each chapter states something like this:

> Cite as:
>
> Sub-author 1, sub-author 2. (year). Chapter title. In: editor 1, editor 2 (eds): *Report title.*

Is there a proper way to cite something in this way using BibTeX? I haven't found anything useful through searching. Should I just cite the overall work, or should I take details from both to come up with a more usual citation entry that doesn't include "In:"?

Comment: It really depends on the bibliography style (the `.bst`) you use, but it is common for them to have `@inbook`, `@incollection`, and `@inproceedings`.  As to which one works best, it will depend on your best judgment as to which entry type suits your requirements best.

Comment: See also [How to cite a chapter in a book with BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60843/5001).