# BibTex: How to cite the author of preamble of another author?

Tags: bibtex

I don't know how to make the BibTex entry of the following case:
The entire book is from one author A, but the editor (author B) wrote only the preamble and I need to cite this preamble, and I don't know how to do it.

It is not this case
[How to cite a book chapter written by an author who is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60843/how-to-cite-a-book-chapter-written-by-an-author-that-is-not-the-editor-or-author)
because I think I'll need 2 different fields to different authors.

Comment: Let me sure I understand this: The book has both an editor -- who is also the author of the Preface (but, presumably, no other part) -- and an author, who wrote all of the book *except* the preface? Are both the editor and the author listed on the book's jacket and on the title page? Could you maybe post an online link to this book if it's available on, say, Amazon?

Comment: Yes, you understood very well. And well, its a german book: [AmazonLink](http://www.amazon.com/Theorie-sozialen-Interaktionsmedien-Studienb%C3%BCcher-Sozialwissenschaft/dp/3531214934). And here a link to an example of the citation code of the book (BibTex included): [bibsonomyLink](http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2c7a28f37437eaa68220fbc0d79e3db12/loso)

Answer (score 2):

A minor variation on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60855/5001) to the posting [How to cite a book chapter written by an author that is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60843/5001) should work for you. Note that the `author` and `editor` fields contain the same information.

If you believe it's either necessary or advisable to mention the name of the author of the rest of the book, you can do so by adding a `note` field -- see the example below -- or by adding the author's name, in parentheses, to the `booktitle` field. The choice will likely depend in part on publishing conventions (about which you haven't told us much so far).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{xyz,
   author    = "EditorFirstName EditorSurname",
   editor    = "EditorFirstName EditorSurname",
   title     = "Preface",
   booktitle = "Booktitle",
   publisher = "Publisher",
   address   = "SomeTown",
   pages     = "xv--xxiii",
   note      = "(Author: A. AuthorSurname)",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % select a bibliography style

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, first error: I used `@InBook` instead of `@InCollection`.

Comment: My solution was then to put the autor in the field editor: `Editor= {Parsons, Talcott(aut.) and Stefan Jense}` and `(ed.)` appear automaticaly when compiled:  It gave me a much better result, but the `(aut.)` disappeared in the compilation. Not so bad: `JENSE, S. Einleitung. In: PARSONS, T.; JENSE, S. (Ed.). Zur Theorie der sozialen Interaktionsmedien. Opladen: Westdeutscher, 1980, (Studienbücher zur Sozialwissenschaft, 39). cap. Einleitung, p. 7–10`.