# bibtex: single author book with introduction by different author

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I've got a single-author, single-piece book (i.e., not a collection of chapters articles, or stories) which has an introduction by a separate author.  I'm trying to cite the introduction.

`@incollection` isn't right, because you can't give the collection as a whole a single author, only an `editor`; `@inbook` isn't right, because you can't give two different authors, one for the piece and one for the book.  Is `@misc` my only option?

Here's what I've got (which doesn't work: the `bookauthor` field doesn't display when I compile):

```
@incollection{jones,
  author={Gwyneth Jones},
  title={Introduction},
  bookauthor={Joanna Russ},
  booktitle={The Female Man},
  publisher={Gollancz},
  series={SF Masterworks},
  year={2010},
  pages={ix--xii},
}
```

Comment: Note that the options offered at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275813/bibtex-how-to-cite-the-author-of-preamble-of-another-author still list the author of the book-as-a-whole as an editor, rather than an author.

Comment: With `biblatex` you could use `@suppbook` (or `@inbook`), but I guess with most BibTeX styles you are out of luck. You could try moving the field contents around a bit and abusing field contents, but what works will definitely depend on the style you use.

Answer (score 2):

With `biblatex` you would use `@suppbook` or `@inbook`. `@suppbook` is explained by the `biblatex` documentation as

> Supplemental material in a `@book`.
>   This type is closely related to the `@inbook` entry type.
>   While `@inbook` is primarily intended for a part of a book with its own title
>   (e.g., a single essay in a collection of essays by the same author),
>   this type is provided for elements such as prefaces, introductions,
>   forewords, afterwords, etc.
>   which often have a generic title only.
>   Style guides may require such items to be formatted differently
>   from other `@inbook` items.
>   The standard styles will treat this entry type as an alias for `@inbook`.

There is, in fact, one (and only one) difference in the output between `@suppbook` and `@inbook` in the `biblatex` standard styles: The `title` of `@inbook` is wrapped in quotation marks, whereas the `title` of `@suppbook` is unformatted.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@suppbook{jones:suppbook,
  author     = {Gwyneth Jones},
  title      = {Introduction},
  bookauthor = {Joanna Russ},
  booktitle  = {The Female Man},
  publisher  = {Gollancz},
  series     = {SF Masterworks},
  year       = {2010},
  pages      = {ix--xii},
}
@inbook{yones:inbook,
  author     = {Gwyneth Yones},
  title      = {Introduction},
  bookauthor = {Joanna Russ},
  booktitle  = {The Female Man},
  publisher  = {Gollancz},
  series     = {SF Masterworks},
  year       = {2011},
  pages      = {ix--xii},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{jones:suppbook,yones:inbook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jones, Gwyneth (2010). Introduction. In: Russ, Joanna. The Female Man. SF Masterworks. Gollancz, pp. ix–xii.//Yones, Gwyneth (2011). ‘Introduction’. In: Russ, Joanna. The Female Man. SF Masterworks. Gollancz, pp. ix–xii.]

---

If you are not using `biblatex`, but classical BibTeX, there is no obvious good type available for entries like this. Note however, that there are some differences between individual `.bst` styles, the discussion here mainly focusses on the 'standard styles' `plain.bst` and friends and the 'standard' fields and types as discussed in the [BibTeX documentation on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex).

`@inbook` would probably be the first choice, but it usually doesn't have the `booktitle` `biblatex` has, so you would give the title of the book in `title` and would have to give the chapter title in `chapter`, furthermore you can't have two authors.

`@incollection` has the obvious disadvantage that the author of the book could only be given as `editor`, which would not be accurate. Since something like "ed." would appear in the output, this is a no-go.

So you will have to resort to some creative abuse of fields.

As [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) says

> 2. The standard style’s thirteen entry types do reasonably well at formatting most entries, but no scheme with just thirteen formats can do everything perfectly.
>      Thus, you should feel free to be creative in how you use these entry  types  (but  if  you  have  to  be  too  creative,  there’s  a  good  chance you’re using the wrong entry type).
> 3. Don’t  take  the  field  names  too  seriously.   Sometimes,  for  instance,  you might have to include the publisher’s address along with the publisher’s name in the `publisher` field, rather than putting it in the `address` field.
>      Or sometimes, difficult entries work best when you make judicious use of the `note` field.

For example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{jones:inbook,
  author    = {Gwyneth Jones},
  chapter   = {Introduction},
  title     = {\textup{In Joanna Russ:} The Female Man},
  publisher = {Gollancz},
  series    = {SF Masterworks},
  pages     = {ix--xii},
}
@misc{jones:misc,
  author    = {Gwyneth Jones},
  title     = {Introduction},
  note      = {\textup{In Joanna Russ:}
               \emph{The Female Man.}
               SF Masterworks.
               Gollancz, 2010,
               pp.~ix--xii},
  publisher = {Gollancz},
  series    = {SF Masterworks},
  year      = {2010},
  pages     = {ix--xii},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

That isn't pretty, but it produces usable *output* here.

What exactly works will also depend on the bibliography style you use and what you expect.