# Bibitems in bibitem

Tags: bibliographies

In my paper I want to refer to different sections out of one book. This book is already a `bibitem`. Now, for example, I want to refer to `§1.2 p.55, §2.5 p.144` and `§3.9 p.200`. How to make this happen in a `thebibliography` environment without mentioning the whole `author+book+publisher` for all the references? 
Example:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1}
John A. Rice, Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis Third Edition,Duxbury Advanced Series (2007)
\bibitem{2} §1.2 p.55
\bibitem{3} §2.5 p.144
\bibitem{4} §3.9 p.200

\bibitem{5}
Alvin C. Rencher, Linear Models in Statistic; Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics (2000)

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
```

This is a possibility but not a very nice one. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have so far in the shape of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? I'm a bit confused because you have it over `bibitem`s and `thebibliography`, but your question is tagged `biblatex` and `enumerate`.

Comment: I inserted a possible solution, but not a very elegant one

Comment: I re-tagged your question as it is not about `biblatex` at all, but I still don't quite get what you try to get at.

Answer (score 3):

You can add extra information in a citation with e.g. `\cite[\S1.2]{1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
We refer to \cite[\S1.2 p.55]{Rice07}, and later \cite[\S2.5 p.144, \S3.9 p200]{Rice07}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Rice07}
John A. Rice, Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis Third Edition, Duxbury Advanced Series (2007)
\bibitem{Rencher00}
Alvin C. Rencher, Linear Models in Statistic; Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics (2000)
\end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

[image: cite example]

If it's sections with different authors, there's a solution using Bibtex  for this question [How to cite a book chapter written by an author that is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60843/how-to-cite-a-book-chapter-written-by-an-author-that-is-not-the-editor-or-author). Bibtex also has `crossref` to reference other bib entries.