# bibtex with inbook and book crossref: why is crossref missing$ = True, although crossref is recognized?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I am using bibtex to organize my bibliography. I want to cite a chapter from a book. The best way I read when one has both author and editors, is to use crossref and an inbook and book entry, e.g.: (bib_test.bib)

```
@inbook{inbook,
  author = {A. Inbook-Author},
  title = {The title of the inbook entry},
  pages = {1--5},
  chapter = {1},
  crossref = "book",
}

@book{book,
  title = {A title of the book entry},
  booktitle = {A title of the book entry},
  year = 2013,
  editor = {E. Book-Editor},
  publisher = {Book Publishing Inc.},
}
```

However, if I run bibtex, on a latex file

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\cite{inbook}
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{bib_test}
\end{document}
```

it always gives me the warning:

```
Warning--can't use both author and editor fields in inbook
```

I don't understand this, since that was the reason I splitted it into inbook and  book, but still I am gettings this error. In the bibstyle file I found

```
FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    } 
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  title empty$ 'skip$ 'setup.inlinelink if$ % urlbst
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.edition output 
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.publisher.address output
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$

  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.doi output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

I tested a few things and it seems that crossref missing$ gives always True as an answer. He should NOT test on both author and editor fields being present if a crossref is given. This is weird, since he definitely recognizes the crossref, otherwise he would show an error...

Comment: Please show not only code snippets but a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Is there a good reason for using old BibTeX instead of `biblatex` with `biber`?

Comment: I have added a MWE. Not that I know of, I always used bibtex in combination with pdflatex. Is there an advantage of using biblatex? What is biber?

Comment: I'm still confused by this behaviour. `crossref missing$` is always true, no matter if crossref field exists or not. Similarly, `crossref empty$` is always true, even when cross-referencing other records. If so, why the .bst even have `crossref missing$` sections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to change the entry type of the first entry from `@inbook` to `@inproceedings`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{inbook,
  author = {A. Inbook-Author},
  title = {The title of the inbook entry},
  pages = {1--5},
  chapter = {1},
  crossref = "book",
}
@book{book,
  title = {A title of the book entry},
  booktitle = {A title of the book entry},
  year = 2013,
  editor = {E. Book-Editor},
  publisher = {Book Publishing Inc.},
  address   = "Anytown",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{style} % downloaded from site indicated by OP

\begin{document}
\cite{inbook}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of the "inbook" type then?

Comment: @Guiste - I believe `@inbook` should be used only if the piece being cited is something like a chapter in a book -- and if the chapter and the entire book have the same author (or editor). For a multi-author anthology that was edited by one or more persons who needn't be same as the authors of any of the chapters, the entry type `@inproceedings` should be used. Note that the ``@inproceedings` entry type isn't just limited to conference proceedings -- anthologies will do as well.

Comment: @Guiste -- See also the posting [How to cite a book chapter written by an author that is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60843/5001)

Comment: this is exactly my case. So I want to cite a chapter out of a book with the same author for the chapter and the book, but additionally editors for the whole book, how to handle that?

Comment: @Guiste - Is the entry type `@inproceedings` not working for you? It would help if you edited your posting and replaced the two "dummy" entries with real (or at least more realistic) entries.

Comment: It is working, but I don't understand why I have to use it. I am crossreferencing to a book not proceedings...

Comment: @Guiste - I'm afraid I can't offer any insights into *why* the particular terminology was chosen. BibTeX has been around for more than 30 years, and some of its terminology and jargon could stand a refresher, that's for sure. Just take note of the fact that the `@inproceedings` entry type is quite general and should not be used solely for, well, conference proceedings.