# Citing book chapter from a book series

Tags: bibliographies

I am wondering the best practices for citing a chapter from a book which is part of a book series. I'm having trouble finding good answers online, and it seems from other articles, that there are several ways to do this.

I use Mendeley for my article/book/chapter handling, and the relevant type would be Book Section, but here I can only enter one "Title" and one "Book". My question is then if I should write the Series Name of the Name of this specific Volume in the "Book" field. Or should I completely ignore one of them?

Comment: Does the posting [How to cite a book chapter written by an author who is not the editor or author of the book with BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60843/5001) help? My guess is that you should be using the entry type `@inproceedings`, or its synonym, `@incollection`. If this doesn't help, please provide more, specific information about the publication you wish to cite.

Comment: I've seen the link, but my issue is not completely how to make it look like this or that because I don't know what it should look like in the first place. The question is more on the general style in this case. 
Im looking to cite [this chapter](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-396455-7.00006-6) which, as you will see is chapter 6 of volume 65 of Advances in Quantum Chemistry. The specific volume is called Theory of Heavy Ion Collision Physics in Hadron Therapy.
I am using @incollection, but Mendeley has only one title field and one book field. Not sure what goes in Book field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I visited the publisher's own website for the publication in question, clicked on the "Export to BibTeX" button, and retrieved the following bibliographic entry, minimally pretty-printed. (The only substantive change I made as to take "Chapter Six:" out of the `title` field and create a separate `chapter` field to store this piece of observation.) Observe that the entry type is `@incollection`.

```
@incollection{abril-etal:2013,
  author       = "Isabel Abril and Rafael Garcia-Molina and Pablo de
                  Vera and Ioanna Kyriakou and Dimitris Emfietzoglou",
  title        = "Inelastic Collisions of Energetic Protons in Biological Media",
  editor       = "D{\v z}evad Belki{\'c}",
  booktitle    = "{Theory of Heavy Ion Collision Physics in Hadron Therapy}",
  year         = 2013,
  chapter      = 6,
  pages        = "129--164",
  series       = "Advances in Quantum Chemistry",
  publisher    = "Academic Press",
  volume       = 65,
  number       = "Supplement C",
  issn         = "0065-3276",
  doi          = "https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-396455-7.00006-6",
  url          = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123964557000066",
}
```

You should be able to import this information directly into Mendeley.

Assuming this entry is stored in a bib file called `mybib.bib`, the following MWE, which loads the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style, will format it according to APA, 6th ed. guidelines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\frenchspacing % optional

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{abril-etal:2013}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, many other bibliography styles may be used instead of `apacite`.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of simply exporting the citation from the website, but I will add this: Mendeley was the problem all along!

When importing the citation exported from the website, suddenly a "Series" field shows up for the Mendeley "Type" which is called "Book Section"  (which in bibtex language is called @incollection). This field does not show up otherwise! This was the cause for my confusion all along. I have no idea how one may force this field to appear other than manually importing a citation which has it. (Dragging the pdf into Mendeley is not enough).

Comment: @KasparH - In my own scholarly writing, I have definitely found that I'm much better off *not* using a tool such as Mendeley to manage my bibtex files. For sure, I don't have to waste any time coming to grips with Mendeley's quirks and idiosyncracies -- a form of human capital of rather dubious value...

Comment: May I ask how you organize your citations and pdfs then? Simply a manually created .bib file (or perhaps edited with JabRef etc) and a folder of pdfs?

Comment: @KasparH - I happen to use the WinEdt editor software when working on a Windows machine; it's shareware, but very reasonably priced. (Aside: I actually do most of my work on a Mac; however, because WinEdt runs only under Windows, I do have to switch to a Windows machine when it's time to edit and/reorganize some of the bib files.) From the `winedt.org` website, one can download the `BibMacros` package, which integrates beautifully with the WinEdt editor. Among the many things you'll get from the BibMacros package are super-easy ways to pretty-print, sort, and organize bib files.