# How to cite a book chapter where book author written first after the book title

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am taking the format/idea from [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60843/how-to-cite-a-book-chapter-written-by-an-author-who-is-not-the-editor-or-author)

Chapter title:
[image]

Book title:
[image]

My format is:

The reference taken from here: [enter link description here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=6Kr_DQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Oxford%20Textbook%20of%20Communication%20in%20Oncology%20and%20Palliative%20Care.%202nd&ots=jC_gvppqpo&sig=evDjrstuQMNinhAFuCtcCGYUcpQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Oxford%20Textbook%20of%20Communication%20in%20Oncology%20and%20Palliative%20Care.%202nd&f=false)

```
@incollection{deborah123,
  author      = "Deborah Lewis and Marie O'Boyle-Duggan and Susan Poultney",
  title       = "Communication skills education and training in pre-registeration BSc Nursing",
  editor      = "David W. Kissane and Barry D. Bultz and Phyllis N. Butow and Carma L. Bylund and Simon Noble and Susie Wilkinson",
  booktitle   = "Oxford Textbook of Communication in Oncology and Palliative Care",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2017,
  pages       = "149-154",
  Edition = "2nd edn"
}
```

Output:

[image]

However, I want the output to be where the book author came first, then only book title as shown below:

[image]

```
Lewis, D., O'Boyle-Duggan, M. and Poultney, S. (2017) Communication skills education and training in pre-registration BSc Nursing. In: D. W. Kissane, B. D. Bultz, P. N. Butow, C. L. Bylund, S. Noble and S. Wilkinson, eds. Oxford Textbook of Communication in Oncology and Palliative Care. 2nd edn. Oxford: Oxford University Press, pp. 149-154.
```

My full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{deborah123,
  author      = "Deborah Lewis and Marie O'Boyle-Duggan and Susan Poultney",
  title       = "Communication skills education and training in pre-registeration BSc Nursing",
  editor      = "David W. Kissane and Barry D. Bultz and Phyllis N. Butow and Carma L. Bylund and Simon Noble and Susie Wilkinson",
  booktitle   = "Oxford Textbook of Communication in Oncology and Palliative Care",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2017,
  pages       = "149-154",
  Edition = "2nd edn"
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
% \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}



\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\&\space}


\begin{document}


A book is done \parencite{deborah123}.



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the `ext-authoryear-comp` style, which has an option to do this. `ext-authoryear-comp` is a drop in replacement for `authoryear-comp` but with extra features. The option is called `innamebeforetitle`. See the `biblatex-ext` manual for details.

Also, rather than putting `edition = {2nd edn}` in your bib file, you should just use `edition = {2}` and change the string for `edition`, like this:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{%
  edition = {edn},
}
```

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{deborah123,
  author      = "Deborah Lewis and Marie O'Boyle-Duggan and Susan Poultney",
  title       = "Communication skills education and training in pre-registeration BSc Nursing",
  editor      = "David W. Kissane and Barry D. Bultz and Phyllis N. Butow and Carma L. Bylund and Simon Noble and Susie Wilkinson",
  booktitle   = "Oxford Textbook of Communication in Oncology and Palliative Care",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2017,
  pages       = "149-154",
  edition     = "2"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
  style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  innamebeforetitle,
  dashed=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\&\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{%
  edition = {edn},
}

\begin{document}
A book is done \autocite{deborah123}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks. I try run it, but not the output as your screenshot. It only shown `A book is done deborah123`. Another error it said `Package bibilatex error: Style ext-authoryear-comp not found`. 
I am using `Overleaf` to run it

Comment: @aan, presumably Overleaf does not have `biblatex-ext` as it's version of TeXLive is too old.

Comment: @aan, there are some other options at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate. In fact this question should probably be a duplicate.